# How to Create the database from the variable in the pyspark in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

1.How to create the database using varible in pyspark.Assume we have variable with database name .using that variable how to create the database in the pyspark.

Var a="databasename"

create database a

can you please it is possible to use the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [spark.sql](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql) to execute corresponding [CREATE DATABASE command](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-database.html):

```py
db_name = "some_name"
spark.sql(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db_name}")
```

Comment: it is not working

Comment: 1.The database name is coming from the variable. 2.Using that variable we need to create the database.3. Using that we need to use the database for the rest of the process

Comment: how it isn't working? any error? works just fine

Comment: Thanks Alex. Its working. missed to add brackets